# Why duplicate entry: META-INF/maven/com.samskivert/jmustache/pom.xml althoug I dont use jmustache?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, androidx

In my android app I get this error message:

> Cause: duplicate entry:
>   META-INF/maven/com.samskivert/jmustache/pom.xml

and with more detail:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDependencyCheckerForDebug'.     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
>     //..
>
> Caused by:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.     //..
>
> Caused by:
>   org.gradle.api.artifacts.transform.ArtifactTransformException: Failed
>   to transform artifact 'jarrepack-jmustache.jar
>   (de.example.app.jmustache:jarrepack-jmustache:1.5.1+1.13)' to match
>   attributes {artifactType=android-classes,
>   org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}

I neither use `jarrepack` nor `jmustache` directly. They must be used somewhere in the third-party libs.

That showed up, after [I migrated android libs to androidx libs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) and added

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

to my gradle.properties..

I can compile and build my project, everything is green. 
But when it comes to running on device, I get above error.

**How can I solve my problem?**